# База данных не заполняется или заполняется не правильно в android

Tags: android, sqlite

была следующая задача.Получить json данные с сервера и записать их в локальную бд. Данные пришли,создаю List с пришедшими объектами(фильмами), все хорошо.Как только пытаюсь записать их в бд, они записываются , но объектов становится больше,чем нужно(у меня 6 фильмов) + везде только значения последнего фильма( на всех строках и ячейках бд)

**Код**

**FragmentFilm**

```
public class FragmentFilm extends Fragment {
private View rootView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<FilmItem> filmItemList;
private FilmAdapter filmAdapter;
private DBHelper dbHelper ;
SQLiteDatabase database;




@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    initUi();



    return rootView;
}

private void initUi() {
    filmItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
   database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFilm);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new FilmAdapter(getContext(),filmItemList, (FilmAdapter.FilmAdapterEvents) getActivity()));

    MovieApp.getInstance().movieService.getMovies().enqueue(new Callback<List<FilmJson>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FilmJson>> call, Response<List<FilmJson>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                List<FilmJson> filmJsonList = response.body();
                filmItemList.clear();
                for(FilmJson filmJson: filmJsonList){
                    filmItemList.add(new FilmItem(filmJson));

                }
                for(int i = 0; i < filmItemList.size();i++){
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_TITLE,filmItemList.get(i).getTitle());
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_FAV_STATUS,filmItemList.get(i).getFav_status());
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_DESCRIPTION,filmItemList.get(i).getDescription());
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_IMG,filmItemList.get(i).getImg());
                    Log.d("FilmList",filmItemList.get(i).getTitle());
                }
              
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                database.insert(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME,null,contentValues);
                Cursor cursor =  database.query(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    int titleID = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.FILM_TITLE);
                    do{
                            Log.d("Cursor","title" + cursor.getString(titleID));

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }  else {
                    cursor.close();
                }

                dbHelper.close();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FilmJson>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();

        }
    });



    }


}
```

**DbHelper**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FilmBD";

   public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
   public static final String FILM_TITLE = "title";
   public static final String FILM_FAV_STATUS = "favStatus";
   public static final String FILM_DESCRIPTION = "description";
   public static final String FILM_IMG = "img";


    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null  , DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + DATABASE_NAME + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + FILM_TITLE + " text,"
        + FILM_FAV_STATUS + " integer," + FILM_DESCRIPTION + " text," +
                FILM_IMG + " text" + ")");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

**Логи на примере получения title**

В массиве объектов FilmItem,куда были записаны пришедшие данные

```
   08-04 18:11:15.016 4381-4381/com.example.filmapp D/film: Alice's Adventures in Wonderland
    08-04 18:11:15.016 4381-4381/com.example.filmapp D/film: Iron Man 2
    08-04 18:11:15.016 4381-4381/com.example.filmapp D/film: Avengers
    08-04 18:11:15.016 4381-4381/com.example.filmapp D/film: Avatar
    08-04 18:11:15.016 4381-4381/com.example.filmapp D/film: Shawshank redemption
    08-04 18:11:15.016 4381-4381/com.example.filmapp D/film: The Green Mile
```

Когда пытаюсь из этого массива добавить в бд

```
    08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.652 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.653 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.653 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.653 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
08-04 18:23:25.653 4646-4646/com.example.filmapp D/Cursor: titleThe Green Mile
```

По хорошему, нужно сразу пришедшие данные записать в бд из filmJsonList, но ситуация там в точности такая же.Ошибок никаких не вылетает в логах.

Comment: Сложно что то сказать кроме того, что непонятно что у вас с id фильмов. В бд он не автоинкремент и вы его явно нигде не задаёте вроде. Попробуйте с id разобраться. И используйте room либу для бд. Так низкоуровнево в реальной жизни с БД почти никто не работает

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да тоже самое,ничего  не поменялось с инкрементом. Да я хотел сначала разобраться с локальной БД, а потом уже переходить на room) Буду пробовать с room.

Comment: @Sorulai Автоинкремент не поможет, вам нужно передавать/получать в `json` уникальный идентификатор фильма и записывать его в бд. При записи в БД использовать `insertWithOnConflict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте Room

```
dependencies {
      def room_version = "2.2.5"
    
      implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
      annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" 
}
```

В вашей сущности задайте полю аннотацию

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private Long id = 0
```

В dao классе задайте

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(Data data);
```

OnConflictStrategy используется для выбора действия при конфликте записи в таблицу. Room вам очень поможет, удачи!

Answer (score 0):

ContentValues - это по сути обычная ArrayMap, то есть коллекция ключ - значение (не список).
Вы в цикле постоянно перезаписываете по одним и тем же ключам разные значения, пока в конце не остаются последние значения списка (Green Mile), которые вы и помещаете в базу данных.
Попробуйте помещать в базу данных значение contentValues в конце каждой итерации цикла.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < filmItemList.size();i++){
                        contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_TITLE,filmItemList.get(i).getTitle());
                        contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_FAV_STATUS,filmItemList.get(i).getFav_status());
                        contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_DESCRIPTION,filmItemList.get(i).getDescription());
                        contentValues.put(DBHelper.FILM_IMG,filmItemList.get(i).getImg());
                        Log.d("FilmList",filmItemList.get(i).getTitle());
                    database.insert(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME,null,contentValues);
   }
```